# PHPWebSocket library not working

Tags: php, javascript, html, websocket, phpwebsocket

So I downloaded this library: http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/ and uploaded the example exactly as it is to my server. I ran it with chrome and got `WebSocket - status 0` for a long time, and after that `Disconnected - status 2`. I checked and my server DOES support sockets. You can see the source code in the link to the library, and here is where I uploaded this to: http://tamir.netspot.co.il/websocket/. So can anyone help me figure out what the problem is?

Comment: how do you know that your server supports sockets? shared servers often don't allow you to use sockets.

Comment: First, it's not really "shared", my friend gave me this (he owns the netspot.co.il domain), and second, phpinfo() says it does.

Comment: by shared, i mean that the server that the domain is hosted on is a shared server used by multiple websites. do you know what company hosts your website? they would have info about this. also, phpinfo() while it would tell you whether the socket functions are available, it would not tell you whether your script would have access to the actual sockets. this doesn't have much to do with php, it has more to do with security and the way that your server is set up.

Comment: Note: the websocket server runs as a script on the server, not through the web server.  By setting this to a different port, the server could have all unknown ports blocked.  Say you run the server on 12345, the firewall for the server, could be denying that connection, even if you are running the server.

Comment: Tried many ports, still didn't work.

Comment: @Cokegod chances are you don't have access to create socket connections unless your domain is run on a Virtual Private Server. after a failed connection try echoing socket_last_error(). http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-last-error.php

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

On the server php script make sure you are using the host **tamir.netspot.co.il** and not **localhost**